# Azure Devops pipelines to trigger on PR complete

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What I have to do is, I have 1 branch as below in the azure DevOps respository

1. dev

Then I create a new branch as dev-C123456, so now I have two branches (`dev` and `dev-C123456`)

Then I do some changes to `dev-C123456` and I create a Pull Request from `dev-C123456` to `dev`. So once the changes are reviewed, the approver will `Approve` and `Complete` the pull request.

Right after he clicks Completes, I want a pipeline to run.

Here's my

And I have a `auzre-piplines-on-pr.yml` which will trigger the pipeline. For example, in dev branch, I have like this;

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
...
```

But it never triggers a pipeline, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> Right after he clicks Completes, I want a pipeline to run.

So put a trigger for the target branch.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
```

That will run whenever a commit is made to `dev`, including when the commit is a PR merge commit.

Comment: Yes, but  `that will run whenever a commit is made to dev` not only if a PR merge commit..

Comment: @DavidMuñozTord Do you think that means that this is not an appropriate answer to the question that was asked?

Comment: Well it "works" in this case, but for example in my case it doesn't. This is not specific to a PR request but will run anytime the DEV branch is changed.

Comment: @DavidMuñozTord Feel free to ask a question if you have a different scenario that you're having trouble implementing.

Comment: here is the new question if people resent the need as I do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053721/azure-devops-pipelines-to-trigger-only-on-merge